# Keras fit_generator - ImageDataGenerator behaviour

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I was using the `fit` function for a while now, but now I need to make some augmentation to the dataset that I have, so I have to use `fit_generator`. There are some things I don't understand about `fit_generator`.

Why there is a `batch_size` option inside flow function? How does it behave when I use it with the `steps_per_epoch` parameter? Is there a way to know how many images are generated with the imagedatagenerator function?

```
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x, y,batch_size=32), steps_per_epoch=len(x)/32,epochs=50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data generator produces batches of data, meaning that for image data it produces numpy arrays with the shape `(batch_size, image_height, image_width, channels)`. `fit_generator` takes these batches one at a time (and trains on them, obviously). `steps_per_epoch` defines the number of batches in an epoch. The number of images generated per batch is whatever you tell it, and the total number of images is infinite (though it will eventually loop around and start producing duplicates)

Comment: okay, so I give my entire set to flow function and it takes images from the set randomly and generates images batch by batch, because at first I thought that it generates something like 5 alternatives to an image, but since it is random is every epoch will have different set of images if so is it bad.

Comment: @can Yes, it generates image batch by batch. The ImageDataGenerator part of it does transformations on each image, but doesn't make different versions of the same image until it's gone through the whole dataset once. It is definitely not bad; it's a standard way of doing training.